# Adding / updating forms on mobile app from server

Tags: android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch

We want to develop a mobile application for android and iOS, in which we need to provide functionality to add new forms from server side or edit existing forms to add new form fields.

In this forms we need to provide functionality to access GPS, camera, we also need to provide maps with pin drag and drop functionality to choose location.

So based on some articles, they have mentioned that using phonegap we can achieve this. As we dont have experience using phonegap we would like to know

1. Are there any limitations/known issues using phonegap for above mentioned functionality.
2. Can we achieve this using sencha touch. Means can we push updates for sencha code remotely.

Feel free to give any suggestions, links to articles that can give us some direction. Thank you.

Comment: what limitations\ problems you got ? there's no problem to make dynamic forms by getting data from JSON

Comment: @DekelMaman yes we can achieve but it will take too much time to write code for all UI components, it will also include UI navigations where multiple forms are linked with each other and actually the main concern is if something goes wrong we will need to update the application. As the data entry part is very much important we will need to fix it immediately, as we know apple approval may take seven days and that will be too much delay.

Comment: in your JSON just include the type of the current field and make some method that get the field type and create the correct object and adding it to your view... actually is not that hard :)

Comment: do you have JSON for example ?

Comment: Yes we have format of json for one screen, do you have any sample json format which can be used for multiple screens and navigations.

Comment: send me sample JSon i try to help you with that

Comment: @DekelMaman thanks for your help, json based option was cancelled due to duration limit, now we are looking for implementing it using phonegap or sencha. Let me know if you have any idea about this.

Comment: sorry i have no knowledge in phonegap :)